# Add xul element to xul of Services.appShell.hiddenWindow

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

This is erroring:

```
Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'browser');
```

This is probably because `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` is an html document. How to add to `Services.appShell.hiddenWindow` it doesnt seem to have a `.document`

---

interesting notes:

```
Services.appShell.hiddenWindow != Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem).rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can create `<browser>` nodes, can you try an `iframe` instead?

Comment: Thanks erik for a reply! It's a curious thing. hiddenDOMWindow is html document im thinking hiddenWindow is xul. But mac native menu is able to create xul elements in the hiddenDOMWindow: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/91ac5c5343ed791cea86#comment-1319720  i need browser because i intend to do docShell swapping :(